# Resurrect `screen` window in its original directory

Tags: gnu-screen

I currently have a `screen` file which I use to automatically open windows that watch the Grunt build in two different related projects (simplified):

```
sessionname popcorn
zombie kr

chdir srv
screen -t "srv grunt watch"     1 grunt watch

chdir ../client
screen -t "client grunt watch"  2 grunt watch
```

Works fine, until it occasionally want to kill and restart one of the Grunt processes. If I kill the `srv` watcher and then restart it, it's now in the wrong directory, and if I chdir in order to make that one start, restarting the client watcher now fails.

Is there a way to make a screen window be "sticky" to the directory that it was originally started in, so that it retains its directory after being killed and restarted? Is there an alternate approach which will accomplish the same thing?

Comment: What if you `chdir` before the kill and restart?

Comment: @HaukeLaging that's what I've been doing, but I would like to avoid that manual step.

Comment: Short of a good solution: You may come closer to what you want by running screen within screen. The "sub-screens" each have only one `chdir` so this problem cannot arise.